# Is there a way i can view others Users Alert settings

Tags: 2013, administration, alert, site-settings

I am the farm admin and the site collection admin for an on-premises sharepoint team site. now some users are complaining that they are not receiving any alerts on a discussion board list, when items are being added. so i want to check the User Alert setting. so i went to "Site Settings" >> "Site Administration" >> "User alerts" >> i select the user >> click on Update.
Now i can see the alert and delete it, as follow:-

[image]

but i am unable to view the whole alert setting,to see if it is was set correctly. while i can do this for the alerts i created. so my question is if there is a way i can view the alerts' setting for other users (in other words can i view the alerts settings for alerts i did not create)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it via PowerShell

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$oWeb = Get-SPWeb "url"
foreach($alert in $oWeb.Alerts)
{    
    Write-Host ([String]::Format("User: {0} has alert on List: {1} in {2} frequency", $alert.User.Email, $alert.List.Title, $alert.AlertFrequency))
}
```

Comment: and what is this suppose to return ? when i run it i got something as follow `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlert Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlert Microsoft.SharePoint.S
PAlert Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlert Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlert Microsoft.Share
Point.SPAlert Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlert Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlert Microsof
t.SharePoint.SPAlert Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlert Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlert `

Comment: It will list you the `User id`.. Try without `Write-Host`.. Updated my answer

Comment: Update more cleaner version!!

Comment: thanks for the updated script, but how i can know the detailed settings for the User alert, such as "Send Alerts for These Changes" OR "Change Type" selection .. this what i am searching for as the frequency and the list name will be shown inside the UI already..

Comment: Explore `$alert` object it has all available/possible objects..